# need help php pdo prepare sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I'm working on a PDO function that allows you to perform a search based on serial number or article id of a tool. However I would like to be able to search both at the same time with a "-" between the id_art and num_serie by writing for example in my search bar 459999-1.

I tried to put a "-" but no result

```
public static function findAllByIdArt($id){

    $id='%'.$id.'%';
    $c=base::getConnection();
    $query=$c->prepare("select * from outillage where (id_art like :num_serie) or (num_serie like :num_serie) or (num_serie and id_art like :num_serie '-' :id_art)");
    $query->bindParam(':num_serie',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':id_art',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $dbres=$query->execute();
    $d=$query->fetchAll();
    $tab=array();
    foreach ($d as $key => $value) {
        $a=new Outillage();
        $a->id=$value['id'];
        $a->num_serie=$value['num_serie'];
        $a->id_art=$value['id_art'];
        $a->article=$value['article'];
        $a->id_doc=$value['id_doc'];
        $a->document=$value['document'];
        $a->ilot=$value['ilot'];
        $a->emplacement=$value['emplacement'];
        $a->liste_tubes=$value['liste_tubes'];
        $a->image=$value['image'];
        $a->image2=$value['image2'];
        $a->image3=$value['image3'];
        $a->image4=$value['image4'];
        $a->image5=$value['image5'];
        $a->nb_utilisation=$value['nb_utilisation'];
        $a->conforme=$value['conforme'];
        $a->dateNonConfo=$value['dateNonConfo'];
        $tab[]=$a;
    }
    return $tab;
}
```

Comment: `or (num_serie between :num_serie and :id_art or id_art between :num_serie and :id_art` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: ty but no. i want to search two column in my search bar when i write for exemple: 6999-01 6999= id_art in my data base and 01= num_serie. I can already search num_serie or id_art but not the both with the '-' (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

your last part of the Statement must look like:

```
(num_serie like :num_serie '-' :id_art and id_art like :num_serie '-' :id_art)"
```

The column must followed by the value. you can not use `column1 and column2 like value`

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

1. Queries cannot do `num_serie and id_art`, you need to explicitly state what value the column should be looking for, not a series of columns. So it should be `num_serie LIKE 'a' AND id_art LIKE 'a'`, for example.
2. Concating the dash could be done by using the `CONCAT()` function. This is the best way, as you're using placeholders in your query (as you should be doing!)

If I understand your question correctly, this query does just that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM outillage 
WHERE (id_art LIKE :num_serie) 
   OR (num_serie LIKE :num_serie) 
   OR (CONCAT(num_serie, '-', id_art) LIKE CONCAT(:num_serie, '-', :id_art))
```

Also, doing `LIKE` without any wildcards, you might as well just compare strings normally, using the equality sign `=` instead of the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Thanks qirel i tried your method but doesn't work. Whenever the search of id_art or num_serie work

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand that last sentence. Whenever they work, then what? Can you describe it a bit better, please?

Comment: Sorry i wanted to say the search of num_serie or id_art work even with the last condition (CONCAT(num_serie, '-', id_art) LIKE CONCAT(:num_serie, '-', :id_art)) in contrary of (num_serie and id_art like :num_serie '-' :id_art)" (sorry for my english). I searched CONCAT() and i thinks it's what i need to cotinue ty

Comment: i continue to find a solution  around the CONCAT().

Comment: i'm blocked , i dont find solution the search return othing again and again :/